# Will removing Nvidia Drivers cause any harm?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a Nvidia Geforce GT 630M (Optimus) graphics card. At this point I just want to disable it, but have a laptop that doesn't give the option in the BIOS. Will deleting the Nvidia Drivers (nvidia-304, nvidia-settings, nvidia-xconfig, etc) cause any harm?

Comment: you need to clarify it a bit more, if you delete your video drivers you might end up with a blank screen. It depends on what are you trying to do exactly, to replace it with other version driver or what?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop using the proprietary drivers, simply disable them in your software center -> Additional Drivers by going back to the X.Org Nouveau driver